# How to highlight area on map if user input any area?

Tags: php, mysql, maps, wikimapia

I'm working on a website where user will input country, state and particular area. Suppose if user inputs delhi and submit then in map delhi city should highlight (NOT WITH MARKER). It should be highlighted like wikimapia.

Please help me with this. I'm stuck on it for so many days.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried till now

Comment: i didnt try anything yet . i dnt have any idea about it.http://www.dyngeometry.com/web/Developer.aspx i visit this site. but it is paid service.

Comment: Here its been done on mouseover but you can get the base idea on how to highlight http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/how-to-highlight-the-area-in-google-map-on-mouse-hover

Comment: ohk bro thanks for your reply